# Pgfplotstable with custom header in first column

Tags: header-footer, pgfplotstable

I have the following document

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{
    1 55.00
    2 5.00
    13 5.00
    14 5.00
    15 5.00
    16 15.00
    }{\tabledata}
    \pgfplotstabletranspose[string type, colnames from={0}]{\tabledataT}{\tabledata}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
    precision=3,
    columns/0/.style={string type},
    every head row/.style={
    before row={\toprule}},
    every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule}]{\tabledataT}
\end{document}
```

The resulting table looks like this: [image]
I am looking for a way to replace the elements of the first column with the following row descriptions

```
Degree\\
\shortstack{Test set\\ misclassifications (\%)}.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much messing about, I give up on attempting better elegancy than this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
    1 55.00
    2 5.00
    13 5.00
    14 5.00
    15 5.00
    16 15.00
    }{\tabledata}

    \pgfplotstabletranspose[string type]{\tabledataT}{\tabledata}

    \pgfplotstablecreatecol[
        create col/set list={{Degree},{\shortstack{Test set\\ misclassifications (\%)}}}
    ]{description}{\tabledataT}

    \pgfplotstabletypeset[
        columns={description,0,1,...,5},
        columns/description/.style={string type},
        precision=3,
        every head row/.style={
            output empty row,
        before row={\toprule}},
        every last row/.style={after row=\bottomrule},
        header=false]{\tabledataT}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table width headers as requested]

Comment: Looks good to me! I've seen worse with pgfplotstable.